# How a file system recognized by an OS? What is the role of an OS in file-systems?

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to understand the medium between a file system & an operating system.

Does the operating system take care of any file manipulations?

Comment: The OS is the kernel and the user land tools (and a compiler). Do a search for how the Linux kernel works. You probably want to learn what bit does what. How is less important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/292748/is-file-system-part-of-operating-system)
 on superuser.com by [sysadmin1138](https://superuser.com/users/40218/sysadmin1138):

> The filesystem itself, represented by the physical order of information on a storage-representation, is independent of the OS. The OS contains a driver that allows it to work with the filesystem. Some filesystems may only have one OS that can talk to it, and that OS has that filesystem hardcoded into it (think Novell NetWare's original filesystem); but that doesn't stop some enterprising person from writing such a driver for another OS just because.